# Nenhuma forma de manter os dados do input text após submit?

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Queria manter os dados do formulário, após dar um submit na página. Não existe nenhuma forma mesmo?

Comment: existe e já tem resposta aqui no site. Vou procurar o link...

Comment: Opa, se encontrar me passa, não encontrei ainda.

Comment: Normalmente, se for PHP e submit normal, dá pra fazer isso `$nome = isset( $_POST['nome'] )?$_POST['nome']:'';` e no form `<input name ="nome" value="<?php echo htmlentities( $nome ); ?>">`, desde que você mande o `$_POST` pra mesma página que gere o formulário

Comment: Mas tenho que inicializar a variavel com null, certo?

Comment: Não precisa, veja que o ternário do `isset` já está retornando vazio se não tiver o post. Aproveite que não tem nenhuma resposta, clique em [edit] e ponha o seu código da parte PHP e do HTML, que fica mais fácil postar um exemplo.

Comment: porém vou passar mais dados, além do nome e vou jogar para uma função que irá trazer um resultado do banco de dados.

Comment: De qq forma, vc tem que [edit] explicar direitinho na pergunta o fluxo dos dados e de preferencia por um exemplo mínimo de código do jeito que vc está fazendo agora, pra facilitar quem for dar respostas. A essência é o que eu pus no comentário, que é preencher o `value` com a informação, independente de onde vem os dados

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="POST" >
            <?php
              $user = (!empty($_POST['user'])) ? $_POST['user'] : '';
             ?> 
            <input type="text" name="user" id="user" value="<?php echo htmlentities( $user ) ; ?>" />
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```